# JavaScript not running on formLoad, CRM 2011 for outlook

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, outlook-2010, form-load

I have recently added CRM 2011 for Outlook client to a new machine, I have a script which runs on the payment entity formLoad which calculates the remainingAmount left after taking into account all the payment allocations and deducting from the TotalAmount..

However, when I access the data through Outlook, the script seems to not be firing off on formLoad.. If i access the same data through the web portal then the script fires off without an issue - this leads me to think that there is a setting somewhere which you need to enable to allow custom javascript to run in Outlook for the CRM?

My script is below for the paymentLoad():

```
        function PaymentOnLoad() {
        setTimeout(attachEventToGrid, 2500);

        if (crmForm.ObjectId != null) {
            var PaymentAmount = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_accountpaymentamount").getValue();

            var OSAmount = CalcOutstandingPaymentAmount(crmForm.ObjectId);
            Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_remainingamount").setValue(parseFloat(eval(rounddec(OSAmount))));

            if ((PaymentAmount != null) && (OSAmount - PaymentAmount != 0)) {
                Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("new_paymentamount").setDisabled(true);
            }
        }
    }
    function rounddec(value) {
        return Math.round(value * 100) / 100;
    }
    function attachEventToGrid() {

        // Attach a refresh event to the PaymentAllocations grid
        var targetgrid = document.getElementById("PaymentAllocations");

        if (targetgrid) {
            if (targetgrid.control.add_onRefresh != undefined) {
                targetgrid.control.add_onRefresh(ReLoad);
            }
            else {
                targetgrid.attachEvent("onrefresh", ReLoad);
            }
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(attachEventToGrid, 2500);
        }
    }
    function PaymentAllocationOnLoad() {
        OnPaymentTypeSelection();
        if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_payment").getValue()[0] != null) {


            var OSPaymentAmount = CalcOutstandingPaymentAmount(Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_payment").getValue()[0].id);
            Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_paymentremainingamount").setValue(parseFloat(eval(OSPaymentAmount)));

            if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_invoice").getValue() != null) {
                var OSInvoiceAmount = CalcOutstandingInvoiceAmount(Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_invoice").getValue()[0].id);
                Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_invoiceremainingamount").setValue(parseFloat(eval(OSInvoiceAmount)));
                Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("new_paymentamount").setDisabled(true);
            }
        }
    }
    function CalcOutstandingPaymentAmount(paymentid) {
        _oService = new FetchUtil(_sOrgName, _sServerUrl);
        var sFetchPayment = "<fetch mapping='logical'>" +
            "<entity name='new_payment'>" +
            "<attribute name='new_paymentamount' />" +
            "<attribute name='new_accountpaymentamount' />" +
            "<filter type='and'>" +
            "<condition attribute = 'new_paymentid' operator='eq' value='" + paymentid + "'/>" +
            "</filter>" +
            "</entity>" +
            "</fetch>";

        var fetchResultPayment = _oService.Fetch(sFetchPayment, null);

        var sFetch = "<fetch mapping='logical'>" +
            "<entity name='new_paymentinvoiceallocation'>" +
            "<attribute name='new_allocatedamount' />" +
            "<filter type='and'>" +
            "<condition attribute = 'new_payment' operator='eq' value='" + paymentid + "'/>" +
            "</filter>" +
            "</entity>" +
            "</fetch>";

        var fetchApplication = _oService.Fetch(sFetch, null);

        var TotalAmount = 0;

        if (fetchResultPayment != null) {
            TotalAmount = fetchResultPayment.results[0].attributes.new_accountpaymentamount.value;
        }

        if ((fetchResultPayment != null) && (fetchApplication != null)) {
            for (var i = 0;
    i < fetchApplication.results.length;
    i++) {
                TotalAmount -= fetchApplication.results[i].attributes.new_allocatedamount.value;
            }
        }
        return TotalAmount;
    }
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: There's no setting to enable running form scripts in CRM for Outlook. The most common issue for this behavior is that customization is not properly synced to the Outlook client. Try clearing the CRM Addin cache and if that does not help remove and add the organization to force a full load of the CRM metadata.

Comment: @Filburt Unfortunately it didn't help removing the CRM cache and then re-adding the organization to force a complete resynch.. Any other suggestions?